# Avoid duplicates when inserting data into a SQL Server table without unique column

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, duplicates

I'm archiving a certain table on regular basis and would like to avoid having duplicates in that archive. There is no unique column in my table, so I'm currently using the following approach:

```sql
INSERT INTO archive (colA, colB, colC)
    SELECT
        colA, colB, colC
    FROM 
        dim.source src
    WHERE
        CONCAT(src.colA, src.colB, src.colC) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(colA, colB, colC) FROM archive)
```

This works, but given that archive contains >40M rows it's quite slow (10+ minutes). Are there any more efficient options?

Thanks!

I've tried several other solutions on stackoverflow, but they didn't work for me and result in an error message

Comment: I'm confused.  MySQL does not support table names that start with `#`.

Comment: I'm not working in MySQL, but SQL. The stackoverflow search brought up results for both though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL allows tuple comparison, so you don't need CONCAT:

```
WHERE (src.colA, src.colB, src.colC) NOT IN (SELECT colA, colB, colC FROM archive)
```

That kind of function use eliminates the possibility of taking advantage of any indexes; but I am not sure how efficient tuple comparisons are either, so this might be better:

```
LEFT JOIN archive AS a ON src.A = a.colA AND src.B = a.colB AND src.C = a.colC
WHERE a.archive_id IS NULL -- archive_id can be replaced with any field from archive you know would not be null if there were a match.
```

and when none of those work well, you can always try a correlated subquery instead:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM archive WHERE colA = src.A AND colB = src.B AND colC = src.C)
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, I would suggest `on duplicate key update`:

```
create unique index unq_test_all on test(colA, colB, colC);
```

And then:

```
insert into test (colA, colB, colC)
    select colA, colB, colC
    from dim.source s
    on duplicate key update colA = values(colA);
```

Comment: I'm working in an SQL environment, should have clarified, sorry

Comment: @Berbatov MySQL is SQL, so is Postgres, and Oracle, etc.... Do you mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: I do (MS SQL Server)